# How to specify different buld dirrectories for qmake?

Tags: c++, qmake

I use qmake. I have the following project structure:

```
/
|_SFMLWidgets
| |_...
| |_View.h
| |_View.cpp
| \_...
|
|_MapEditor
| |_...
| |_View.h
| |_View.cpp
| \_...
|
\_main.cpp
```

This views do different things. When I try to compile project I get compilation errors:

```
overriding recipe for target 'debug/View.o'
ignoring old recipe for target 'debug/View.o'
```

It happens because both views are builded in same directory. Is there any way to specify different build dirrectories?

I want something like:

```
/
|_debug
  |_SFMLWidgets
  | |_...
  | |_View.o
  | \_...
  |
  |_MapEditor
  | |_...
  | |_View.o
  | \_...
  |
  |_main.o
  \_main.exe
```

[My .pro file](https://gist.github.com/sda97ghb/d63cb8c0f5233c555beee55f08b77a00)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put each of SFMLwidgets and MapEditor in separate subdirs qmake project files. Shared configuration of the two subprojects can go into a pri file.